# How to enable autofill in Forms while logging in via ajax in Backbone

Tags: ajax, forms, backbone.js

I'd like to create a ajax based login with backbone.js.
That's  my Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">E-Mail</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="E-Mail">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="loginButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Submit" value="Submit">
      <span class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='#register';">Register</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I catch the event via click and handle the login. Everything woks fine so far. 
BUT, browsers don't allow to save the login information. LastPass or Browser internal.

Is there a way to trigger this?

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger the submit event of the form. That way almost all browsers recognize that what you're doin' is an actual submit. Try that and letme know.